# How to get Web2py Table Migration in Google App Engine to work?

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I've been using web2py for a few years, but just starting with deploying to GAE.

I was able to get a simple web2py application running on GAE, then made some modifications which included schema modifications.  I started getting weird errors (an insert failed because a field needed to be a float, when it was explicitly set to be a float constant), and it looks like the schema modifications were not carried out in GAE -- a check of the datastore shows entities w/ the old schema (for example, my problematic float-field is missing).  These migrations worked fine locally (using SQLite).

settings.migrate is set to True, and all tables have migrate set to that value.

Not sure what code I could provide that would be helpful; all define_table calls are pretty standard.

As for the question(s):

What, if anything, do I need to do to make these migrations work?  If it involves removing the current Entities for my tables (so new ones, with the right schemas, can be created), how would I go about doing that?  (My Datastore Admin page is completely blank.)  Might this be related to the fact that trying to truncate a table on GAE fails?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the new fields from floats to doubles; not sure where (web2py or GAE, or the interface between the two) the issue w/ floats came from, but this was an easy way to route around it.